# Packer azure update existing shared image gallery image

Tags: packer

I'm trying to update an existing shared image in an Azure Shared Image Gallery and I keep getting an error during the build that states "the managed image named oracle.8.3.4.base already exists in the resource group rg-sig-qa-eastus, use the -force option to automatically delete it."

I'm using the following snippet. Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

```
source "azure-arm" "linux_kube_docker" {
  client_id                         = var.client_id
  client_secret                     = var.client_secret
  subscription_id                   = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id                         = var.tenant_id

  location                          = var.location
 

  os_type                           = var.os_type

  shared_image_gallery_timeout      = "2h5m2s"

  azure_tags = {
      environment = "qa"
      source      = "packer" 
  }

  shared_image_gallery {
      subscription   = var.subscription_id
      resource_group = var.gallery_resource_group
      gallery_name   = var.gallery_name
      image_name     = var.managed_image_name
      image_version  = "0.0.1"  # current version
  }
  
  managed_image_name                = var.managed_image_name
  managed_image_resource_group_name = var.managed_image_resource_group

  shared_image_gallery_destination {
    gallery_name        = var.gallery_name
    image_name          = var.managed_image_name
    image_version       = "0.0.2" # new version
    replication_regions = var.replication_regions
    resource_group      = var.gallery_resource_group
  }
  vm_size         = var.vm_size
}

build {
  sources = ["source.azure-arm.linux_kube_docker"]
  
  provisioner "shell" {
    execute_command = "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'"
    inline = ["echo upgrade done!"]
    inline_shebang  = "/bin/sh -x"
  }

  provisioner "shell" {
    execute_command = "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'"
    inline          = [
      "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"]
    inline_shebang  = "/bin/sh -x"
  }
}
```

KC

Answer (score 1):

You're using a managed image for the build that already exists. Packer does copy the captured image to the gallery but doesn't delete it afterward. With `-force` you can overwrite the current image.

I do have a bad experience in reusing the same image version for the gallery, it didn't look like updated after the copy was done.